# print out the nth column of a file in c++

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to make a program that reads an arbitrary column of a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in_file("/tmp/testfile");
    int n_skip = 2;
    std::string tmpword;
    while (in_file) {
        if(n_skip < 0) {
            throw "Column number must be >= 1!";
        }

        // skip words
        while(n_skip > 0) {
            in_file >> tmpword;
            n_skip--;
        }

        in_file >> tmpword;
        std::cout << tmpword << "\n";
        in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it always prints the first column, why?

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: n_skip will have a value of 0 for most of this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the outer `while` loop is executed the first time, `n_skip` is set to 2. However, when you execute

```
    while(n_skip > 0) {
        in_file >> tmpword;
        n_skip--;
    }
```

`n_skip` gets set to 0 and is never reset to 2.

Add a line

```
n_skip = 2;
```

after the line

```
    in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I need to restore the value of `n_skip` on every line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in_file("/tmp/testfile");
    int n_skip = 2;
    if(n_skip < 0) {
        throw "Column number must be >= 1!";
    }
    std::string tmpword;
    while (in_file) {
        int n_skip_copy = n_skip;

        // skip words
        while(n_skip_copy > 0) {
            in_file >> tmpword;
            n_skip_copy--;
        }

        in_file >> tmpword;
        std::cout << tmpword << "\n";
        in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```